# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

I'm new here and i'm an absolute beginner.

Please help with that error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in index.php on line 174

First line is line 174

```
( $sql = ||  print mysql_error(  ) );

                        if (0 < mysql_num_rows( $sql )) {

                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql )) {
                                @extract( $row );
                                $numview = ($viewer == 1 ? 'view' : 'views');
                                $numvideo = ($counter == 1 ? 'video' : 'videos');
                                $chanlink = 'index.php?channels=browse&channel_id=' . $uid;

                                if (!empty( $img )) {
                                    $show_images = '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank"><img src="thumbs/channel/' . $img . '" width="' . $chan_img_width . '" height="' . $chan_img_height . '" border"0"></a>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    $show_images = '';
                                }
```

Comment: `( $sql = ||  print mysql_error(  ) );` What in the world is that?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear...

> unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in index.php on line 174

This is line 174:

```
( $sql = ||  print mysql_error(  ) );
```

This is a boolean `OR`:

```
||
```

You can't assign a boolean `OR` operator to a variable, so this doesn't make sense (let alone the rest of the line):

```
$sql = ||
```

The PHP parser doesn't expect things that don't make sense, so it throws an error.

Comment: Now i got this:     Warning: mysql_num_rows(): 21 is not a valid MySQL result resource in index.php on line 176

Comment: @user3441861: Sounds like there was an error executing the SQL command and `$sql` isn't a valid database resource as a result.